# What is wrong with my Python code which detects whether an application (Chrome) is opened or not?

Tags: python, psutil

```
import psutil as psutil

for proc in psutil.process_iter():
    proc_name = proc.name()
    if proc_name == 'chrome.exe':
        print('chrome is running now.')`
```

When I run the above Python code that checks whether an application like Chrome is opened or not on a MacBook M1 after opening Chrome, it does not print the correct result (i.e. Chrome is running now.)

Comment: The executable's name is not `chrome.exe` (the `.exe` suffix is only used on Windows).

Answer (score 0):

For macOS (it will be different on Windows):

```
import psutil

for proc in psutil.process_iter():
    if proc.name() == "Google Chrome":
        print("Chrome is running")
        break
else:
    print("Chrome is not running")
```